# Javascript is not working in the options page of the Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for google chrome. But I'm having trouble using localStorage and also is not working javascript.

See the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ShowAlert() {
                alert("This is a alert!");
            }
        </script>
    </head><body>
        <script>
            ShowAlert();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a simple code that displays a message, it works, I've tested. But when I access as an options page of my extension, the message will not appear.

Have any permission that should be missing in manifest for this to work?

Comment: Inline scripts are not allowed in Chrome extensions. You must move your scripts to a separate file; e.g., `<script src="alertstuff.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute inline scripting, this is a [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. 
>   This restriction bans both
>   inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. < button
>   onclick = "..." > ).
>
> The restriction wipes out a huge class of cross-site scripting attacks
>   by making it impossible for you to accidentally execute script
>   provided by a malicious third-party. It does, however, require you to
>   write your code with a clean separation between content and behavior.

Change your code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <script src="alerter.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and separate code in alerter.js

```
function ShowAlert() {
    alert("This is a alert!");
}
ShowAlert();
```